# Why can I see/trade VIX but not S&P/TSX 60 VIX?

Tags: trading, volatility, vix

I am using Questrade and if I do a look up for `VIX.IN`, I find it:

[image]

However, I can't find `S&P/TSX 60 VIX`:

[image]

Why is this?

I can see that it is being traded...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

S&P/TSX 60 VIX (CAD) is an equation and as the implied volatility of two close to the money TSX 60 options change, the output changes. This is why the intra-day price fluctuates on a graph like a traded product.  Although VIXC can't be traded, it can still be used as an important signal for traders.

The excerpt is from slide 12, more information can be found here.
https://www.m-x.ca/f_publications_en/vixc_presentation_en.pdf

Futures (stage 2) Options, ETFs, OTC Products (stage 3) have not been implemented.[image]

Comment: Does this mean you will be able to trade it after stage 2 and 3 are implemented?

Comment: @karancan Yes and no.  It means that you would be able to trade these instruments (ETFs, options, and OTCs) that use futures to replicate the "daily movements" of the underlying VIXC.  This is different from trading VIXC directly.  VIX related ETFs, for example, are designed and intended for day trading, not long term holdings.

Answer (score 1):

You can trade VXX, but VIX is only an index.   http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/VXX?CountryCode=US